# virtualenvwrapper install on Mac - hook_loader.py pkg_resources not found

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to setup virtualenv & virtualenvwrapper on my mac but am experiencing problems with virtualenvwrapper.

I've looked through the other related posts regarding this and tried some things but I still get an error when my .bash_profile loads on the line

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

error msg:  File "", line 1, in 
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 16, in 
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources*

```
'which python' yields '/usr/local/bin/python'
```

and running IDLE tells me its using v2.7.3

I've previously run

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

and they both appeared to run through fine.

Running a 'find' shows that pkg_resources.py is in 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py

my PATH is 
    /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin

also 
cat .bash_profile  yields

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/workspace/virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/workspace/repos
export PATH=/usr/local/python:$PATH
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Anyone else had this problem and found a fix?

many thanks

Comment: You say that your python is in /usr/local/bin. How did you install it? (Python.app/homebrew/macports...)

Comment: pretty sure its just the pre installed python on the Mac

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error this morning. Upgrading setuptools on my base python environment (not inside a virtual environment) fixed this issue. Here is the command I ran

```
sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

I had setuptools installed before, but maybe I had a bad version or a corrupted install. Upgrading with --upgrade fixed it.